# How to find out in a react component a prop is node or not?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a `React.Component` which has these props:

```
Test.propTypes = {
   ...
   ...
   example: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.object]),
};
```

I need to know in the `render()` method, `example`'s type is node or object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, [here](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L474) is the following for `PropTypes.node` validation:

```
  function isNode(propValue) {
    switch (typeof propValue) {
      case 'number':
      case 'string':
      case 'undefined':
        return true;
      case 'boolean':
        return !propValue;
      case 'object':
        if (Array.isArray(propValue)) {
          return propValue.every(isNode);
        }
        if (propValue === null || isValidElement(propValue)) {
          return true;
        }

        var iteratorFn = getIteratorFn(propValue);
        if (iteratorFn) {
          var iterator = iteratorFn.call(propValue);
          var step;
          if (iteratorFn !== propValue.entries) {
            while (!(step = iterator.next()).done) {
              if (!isNode(step.value)) {
                return false;
              }
            }
          } else {
            // Iterator will provide entry [k,v] tuples rather than values.
            while (!(step = iterator.next()).done) {
              var entry = step.value;
              if (entry) {
                if (!isNode(entry[1])) {
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
```

React only provides the function [`React.isValidElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#react.isvalidelement), so you'd need to implement your own check to determine if it's a valid node, or implement a more specific prop type (ie. `[PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]`), and check that.

Answer (score -3):

#### prop-types doesn't export any of such functions, but we may achieve by doing like below

```
Test.propTypes = {
   ...
   ...
   example: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.object]),
};

import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Test extends component 
{
    render() {
        const isNode = React.isValidElement(example) 
//isNode is false, we consider it as object
    }
}
```

[React.isValidElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L499)

Comment: React.isValidElement is for `element` not for `node`

Comment: could you able to provide test data for example prop?

Comment: React node can be an element, if we say node we always pass component,so isValidElements works,  node like here--> ReactNodeLike =
    | {}
    | ReactElementLike
    | ReactNodeArray
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | undefined;```